# How to count values from a column by id?

Tags: sqlite, count

Table `Vehicles`:

| Unit | Type_vehicle | Vehicle_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | car | 12332 |
| 1 | car | 656 |
| 2 | bike | 534 |
| 2 | car | 98 |
| 2 | truck | 778 |
| 3 | car | 098 |
| 3 | car | 345 |
| 3 | car | 1114 |
| 4 | bike | 234 |
| 4 | bike | 66 |
| 4 | truck | 4 |

I want to know which unit has most cars. I need an output that looks like this:

| Unit | count(cars) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 0 |

In this example, the unit 3 has the most cars. The previous table can be of course sorted and limited to just the unit 3. I want to know how to obtain this output, since I don't know how to count only for cars.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Could use:

```
SELECT
    Unit,
    count(Type_vehicle)
FROM
    Vehicles
WHERE
    Type_vehicle = 'car'
GROUP BY
    Unit
;
```

Or if 0 -count id's should be included:

```
SELECT
    Unit,
    count(Type_vehicle = 'car')
FROM
    Vehicles
GROUP BY
    Unit
;
```